# Reactor in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, reactor

Artem. Glad to see a new version of si. 
Is it possible to use reactor, or rxjava in spring integration flow? 
Like this

For example: 
Input xml with some collection=>reactive splitter->reactive transformer->reactive outbound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all thank you for the feedback and the attention to our work. We are trying to follow with the real world tendencies and go ahead to be always in time ;-).

Well, regarding Reactor or similar Reactive Streams solution.

I'm note sure that it would be good idea to do your "scratch" flow. Even as long as Spring Integration looks like Reactive Streams, it doesn't matter that we should combine them that way.

First of all Spring Integration is a 'managed' flow ad it requires Spring Container, so if you want to combine it with Reactor you should get access to the Spring Container from that code which provides `Stream`. From other side to get access to a Reactor `Stream` from Spring Integration we should make it a Spring bean finally.

The upcoming Spring Integration 4.1 introduces [`Promise<?> Gateway`](https://spring.io/blog/2014/09/05/spring-integration-4-1-milestone-1-available). So if your `Controller` or `Service` is a Spring bean and the code is composed via Reactor `Stream` you get access to the Spring Integration flow using Gateway interface - and the result of that Integration Flow will be populated as an `Event` to the next Stream Action.

Something similar you can do vise versa, when you need a `push` action for the Spring Integration instead of `pull`.

Assume you have Reactor `Deffered` bean:

```
@Bean
public Deffered<Integer, Stream<Integer>> reactorStream() {
    Deferred<Integer, Stream<Integer>> stream = Streams.<Integer>defer(new Environment());
    stream.compose().collect(5).timeout(1000);
    return stream;
}
```

After that we can go ahead and use it from `channel-adapter`:

```
<outbound-channel-adapter channel="reactorStreamChannel" ref="reactorStream" method="accept"/>
```

Anyway I don't recommend to jump from one 'world' to 'another' all the time, because we may lose the best from both of them. Or Reactor Stream is a main flow, all Spring Integration.

I'd be glad to hear some other thoughts from our Reactor team :-).